# Geometric problem with a lvl between TST and IMO.

Tags: geometry

$N$ is the orthogonal projection of $A$ on the side $BC$, and $K$ is the orthogonal projection of $C$ on the side $AB$, and $AN$ and $CK$ intersect in point $H$. Let $k_1$ be the circle around $\triangle ABC$ and $k_2$ the circle around the $\triangle BKN$. Beside the point $B$, $k_1$ and $k_2$ intersect also in point $P$. $CA$ and $BP$ intersect in point $S$, and $SH$ intersects $k_2$ in $Q$. Prove that the intersection point of $NP$ and $QK$ (shown in the diagram as $T$) is on $AC$.

I got that $H$ also has to be on $k_2$, and that points $S$, $C$, $N$, $P$ are on the same circle, $k_3$.
S,C,Q,K are also cyclic.

[image]

Comment: Care to make a diagram?

Comment: I am sry but I am witing this via phone now. I could draw it and take a photo, but where should I put it ?

Comment: @MirzaArnaut: I added a diagram for you. Check that it matches what you expect.

Comment: The fact that $H$ is on $k_2$ is key. This makes $BPNHQK$ a cyclic hexagon, which is then subject to a classical (well, 17th-century) theorem.

Comment: Can you send me a link to that theorem?

Comment: @Blue I knew there was a simpler solution (I was using the dual of the one you mention + Desargues').

Comment: @MirzaArnaut: I could, but there's enough information in my comment for an easy web search. (Another clue: projective geometry.)

Comment: Pascals theorem. I proved in my way, not using projective geometry bcs I dont know that is and if I dont know something I either learn it or dont use it, but bcs I didnt have enough time I just did it my way. Thanks a lot for the helpful hint, @Blue.